# How to read variables added to RequestContext inside class-based generic views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

With regular views, `RequestContext` variables can be accessed just like `request.VARNAME`:

```
def example(request, template_name='stuff_list'):
  return render_to_response(template_name,
      {'stuff_list': get_list_or_404(Stuff, foo=request.DEBUG)},
      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

... instead of setting `context_instance` I could call *function-based generic view*  `direct_to_template`<sup>1</sup>

How do I read variables added to RequestContext inside [*class-based generic views*](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/) <sup>2</sup>?

For example:

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):
  template_name = 'stuff_list'
  bar = request.DEBUG   # This won't work. What should I use instead?
  queryset = get_list_or_404(Stuff, foo=bar)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  Will be replaced by [class-based `TemplateView`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/generic-views-migration/#replace-generic-views-with-generic-classes) anyway.
<sup>2</sup> They are new in Django 1.3 and I want to use them just because.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a callback — `get_queryset()` in this case — instead of the class attributes. Class attributes are really just shortcuts when you're controlling options statically, and they're limited to some pretty simple things. When you need to do something more complex, you'll want to switch to a callback instead.

In your case, code like the following should work:

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'stuff_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_list_or_404(Stuff, foo=self.request.DEBUG)
```

For more details, [see the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#dynamic-filtering).

Comment: Thanks a lot, new class-based generic views made my application even cleaner and smaller. Django team made a great job!

Answer (score 6):

RequestContext parameters are *also regular context variables*. You should be able to do just `{{VARNAME}}`